# Can't make hover handler work for some images but not all images

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$('.downarrow').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400,0.4);
 },function(){ 
  $(this).stop().fadeTo(400,1.0);
    });
```

```css
div.elevator {
      position: fixed;
    }
    img.craft {
      position: fixed;
      left: 100px;
      bottom: 100px;
    }
    img.downarrow {
      position: fixed;
      left: 260px;
      bottom: 540px;
    }
    img.uparrow {
      position: fixed;
      left: 170px;
      bottom: 540px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elevator">
  <img src="./images/spaceelivator.png" alt="elevator" style="width:300px;height:400px" class="craft">
  <img src="./images/down.png" alt="down" style="width:70px;height:95px" class="downarrow">
  <img src="./images/up.png" alt="up" style="width:70px;height:95px" class="uparrow">
</div>
```

This works fine for most of my images in the document but all those images have relative positioning. The ones with fixed positioning don't work. I feel like its something to do with that but i'm not really sure as i'm new to all these languages.

Here is a jsfiddle for the whole site. http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/

Comment: I think we're really gonna need a code snipped that reproduces this problem, in order to be able to solve it

Comment: Could you add a JS Bin?http://jsbin.com/

Comment: btw, if your `elevator` element is already fixed, I don't think the elements inside need to be fixed as well

Comment: @ToddMark no need to use jsbin for this. StackOverflow has a native, runnable code snippet function.

Comment: Do you want it to look like that? http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7dzdj6/embedded/result/

Comment: let me confirm something you added hover effect in .downarrow and it is not applying in all .downarrow... right??

Comment: yes @matthias_h thats what i want, but it is not working for me

Comment: @Hugh I've just changed the selector from $('.downarrow').hover to $('img').hover so it's working for all img. But question is how you want the hover to work - should all img also fade when hovering over another img? Ore only the img that's being hovered?

Comment: @matthias_h   I want .uparrow and .downarrow to fade when you hover over them (seperatly) .elevator shouldn't ever fade.

Comment: @Hugh like that? http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7dzdj6/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @matthias_h yes like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjusted for the comments below OP, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7dzdj6/1/):

```
$('.downarrow, .uparrow').hover(function () {
$(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 0.4);
 }, function () {
$(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 1.0);
});
```

In your code you only applied the `hover()` for `$('.downarrow')`. It's possible to select multiple elements like e.g.  `$('.downarrow, .uparrow')` at once.

**Update:** Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/7/embedded/result/) to easier identify the images in question. Problem is that, while scrolling, the `<div id="wrap">` sometimes covers various images and then the hover won't apply. Can be checked with Web Developer tools e.g. when the moon-image is about upper third of the screen, then `#wrap` covers up and down images.

Comment: While this does work on its own, it doesnt work with my whole site together http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/

Comment: @Hugh Is this working for you or still something missing? http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/4/embedded/result/

Comment: i just tried it in internet explorer and it worked, but it does not work in google chrome for me so it must be a browser issue. You know anything about that?

Comment: @Hugh To easier identify a new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/7/embedded/result/  and maybe I just noticed the problem that you have, as the hover is also working in Chrome for me, but it depends on the scroll position, because the "invisible" #wrap sometimes covers e.g. the up and down arrows, and then the hover won't apply

Comment: @Hugh It's not browser specific, it also doesn't work in Firefox. If moon is about middle/upper third of the page, hover for up and down is not working, too, because #wrap covers both.

Comment: I just removed all the "#wrap" divs and changed the css for "#wrap" to "section" and it fixed it, thanks for the help!

Comment: I am curious that how to make a JSFiddle **result** page? Thanks.

Comment: @ToddMark If you save a Fiddle, you'll notice an additional "Share" entry next to "Collaboration" in the main navigation. The 2nd entry in the "Share" menu is the link for the full sreen result.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is that you applied hover effect only in .downarrow [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/5/)

```
$('.downarrow').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 0.4);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 1.0);
    });
     $('.uparrow').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 0.4);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 1.0);
    });
     $('.craft').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 0.4);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(400, 1.0);
    });
```

Comment: can you tell me which divs are not working with your code and with my code

Comment: All divs here http://jsfiddle.net/bv9wokss/ are working except for the '.elevator' div.

Comment: above code will work but it is creating problem regarding the area of working

Comment: i made elevator cursor pointer so it will help you see the effective area of elevator

Comment: This all works fine in internet explorer but does not work in Google chrome. The elevator cursor pointer doesn't even work in Google chrome.